# Grails 3 Cannot resolve local plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, grails-3.1, grails3

I'm developing a plugin and working locally before publishing. I'd like to avoid publishing until the work is finished.

I've read the latest [Grails Plugins](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins) entry but it doesn't address my issue, nor do the few similar questions here.

My dir structure is like so (a little different than the docs based on [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241100/adding-in-place-plugin-to-grails-3-project)):

```
    PROJECT_DIR
  - settings.gradle
  - myapp
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
  - myplugin
    - build.gradle
```

In myApp build.gradle:

```
  grails {
    plugins {
        compile project(':../myPlugin')
    }
  }
```

In myApp settings.gradle (from the link above):

```
include '../myPlugin'

project(':../myPlugin').projectDir = new File('../myPlugin')
```

Here is the error I'm getting when the build fails:

```
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

...

:../proper-remote:compileWebappGroovyPages UP-TO-DATE
:../proper-remote:compileGroovyPages
:../proper-remote:jar FAILED

...

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':../myPlugin:jar'.
> Could not create ZIP '/Users/me/projects/myPlugin/build/libs/../myPlugin.jar'.

...

Total time: 9.733 secs
| Error Gradle build terminated with error: /Users/me/projects/myPlugin/build/libs/../myPlugin.jar' (No such file or directory)
```

Are my paths incorrect? Do I need to create the jar? If so, how do I do it? I've tried `grails package-plugin` to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://objectcomputing.com/products/grails/multi-project-builds/

In general you don't reference the dependency like a relative folder

`compile project(':myPlugin')`

`include 'myPlugin', 'myApp'`

Additionally, you need to move any info from each app/plugin's settings.gradle to the 'main' one in the parent folder and comment out/remove each app/plugin's setting.gradle file.

Comment: Hi! In addition to not specifying the dependency like a folder, I also realized that I had to move any info from each app/plugin's settings.gradle to the 'main' one in the parent folder and comment out/remove each app/plugin's setting.gradle file.